# App Icon don't appear on my Iphone 6 while appearing on the Iphone 6 from the virtual machine

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I have been blocked on this problem for hours....

I added an AppIcon to my project. If I build it on the virtual Iphone 6 (IOS 8.4), I can see the App Icon while if I build it on my own Iphone 6, the App Icon is still white. This is so frustrating!

If anyone could help me... many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such issue happened to me, when I added icon with transparent background, on simulator everything worked fine, but device showed app without icon. At the same time, try to uninstall app from device and run application again. By the way, check whether you have added all required icons, as another users suggest.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have added all required icons, and my icon has a blue background...

Answer (score 0):

At first, check if you've got some icons in you AppIcon.

[image: AppIcon]

The problem maybe is:

1. you did not set Icon in AppIcon.
2. you did add Icon in AppIcon, but not for `iPhone App iOS 7,8 60pt`
3. other reasons. You should give more specifics so that we can help you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wanted to add screen shoots but I can't since I am a new user.

UPDATE:


I have set Icons in AppIcons


I added AppIcons for Iphone APP iOS 7,8 60 pt


If I build the app on the Iphone 6 virtual machine, I can see the AppIcon while I can't if I do the same on my IPhone..

Comment: delete the app in you own iPhone, then build again.

Comment: @skifen128 60pt is for 1x, You need to add 120x120 pt icon to this "iPhone App iOS 7,8 60pt" 2x position

Comment: I tried deleting the app, clean and then build again : not working :(

Comment: @skifen128 did you change your image's name?  They should be something like "icon.png, icon.png@2x, icon.png@3x" for 3 size image.